# How to prevent InterstitialAd from being closed when Back is pressed

Tags: android, admob

I noticed that my app was receiving few clicks on the InterstitialAd, and I saw that the Ad could be instantly closed by pressing the Back button. Usually the ad takes a few seconds to appear, so the user can close it even before seeing it (when only a black screen appears).

I don't think that it's fair, is almost useless to show it. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

I did this, but nothing happened...

```
// When creating the InterstitialAd, I set the following listener
mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        isShowingInterstitialAd = true;
        mInterstitial.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        isShowingInterstitialAd = false;
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdViewClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

// On the Activity's class
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isShowingInterstitialAd) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that AdMob draws its own Activity on top of yours, so it has its own implementation of `onBackPressed()`, which means that you don't have control of anything that happens once you call `mInterstitial.show();` until AdMob gives control back to your activity.

Comment: Yep, I thought it so too because the Ad opens even if the user exits that Activity and the Context changes

Answer (score 1):

Don't sweat the little things like this.
You are much better off spending energy making your app better.

Some people will never click on ads. But if you provide an inapp purchase that removes the ads they may well buy that. That is a better return on investment for your dev effort.

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, there are a few ways to override that back button. Search for back button override to find them.